# Symfony 3.4: Error Expected type ... Found

Tags: php, symfony

The following error was displayed in intelphense in VS Code.
The same argument is passed in the parent controller, and some different actions do not give an error, so the cause is unknown.
Only `$articleService` of `editAction()` has an error.
There is no error in `createAction()`.
Do you have any idea?

Error

```
Expected type 'App\Ahi\Sp\AdminBundle\Model\Service\BrandService'.  
Found 'App\Ahi\Sp\AdminBundle\Model\Service\ArticleService
```

ArticleController.php

```
    /**
     *
     * @Method("POST")
     * @Route("/{articleType}/", requirements={"articleType"="brandevent"})
     *
     */
    public function createAction(Request $request, EcTrendTagService $ecTrendTagService, BrandService $brandService, ArticleService $articleService, $articleType)
    {
        return parent::newAndCreate($request, $ecTrendTagService, $brandService, $articleService, $articleType);
    }

    /**
     *
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Route("/{articleType}/{id}/edit", requirements={"articleType"="brandevent", "id"="\d+"})
     *
     */
    public function editAction(Request $request, EcTrendTagService $ecTrendTagService, BrandService $brandService, ArticleService $articleService, $articleType, $id)
    {
        return parent::editAndUpdate($request, $ecTrendTagService, $brandService, $articleService, $articleType, $id);
    }
```

BaseArticleController.php

```
    protected function newAndCreate(Request $request, EcTrendTagService $ecTrendTagService, BrandService $brandService, ArticleService $articleService, $articleType)
    {...
    }
    protected function editAndUpdate(Request $request, EcTrendTagService $ecTrendTagService, $articleType, BrandService $brandService, ArticleService $articleService, $id)
    {...
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the wrong order on `parent::editAndUpdate`

PARENT DECLARATION:

```
protected function editAndUpdate(Request $request, EcTrendTagService $ecTrendTagService, $articleType, BrandService $brandService, ArticleService $articleService, $id)
```

What you provide it:

```
parent::editAndUpdate($request, $ecTrendTagService, $brandService, $articleService, $articleType, $id)
```

You send `brandService` third argument when it is expecting `$articleType` and so on, review it so it has the right arguments at the right place.

Comment: Thank you. I made a rudimentary mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Like Yann Chabot said:

Parent declaration:

```
protected function editAndUpdate(Request $request, EcTrendTagService $ecTrendTagService, $articleType, BrandService $brandService, ArticleService $articleService, $id)
{...
```

Your declaration (Wrong) :

```
parent::editAndUpdate($request, $ecTrendTagService, $brandService, $articleService, $articleType, $id)
```

You must declare :

```
parent::editAndUpdate($request, $ecTrendTagService, $articleType, $brandService, $articleService, $id)
```

Regards